# Alignment in \oneof from the phonrule package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics

This question piggybacks off of [the question/answer here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/is-there-a-package-for-formatting-phonological-rules-in-latex?newreg=2ff4e6ce61b34f2cb83ccb8936ee24bd), where one answer mentions how to create a phonological rule using the `phonrule` package.

MWE here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{phonrule}

\begin{document}

\phon{x}{\oneof{
\envr{w}{z} \\
\envl{v}{\phonfeat{
+feature x \\
-feature y}}}}

\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

You can see that output and environments are centered.  Is there any way to un-center them and/or left-align them?  The centering that it does appears to be an intentional addition in v1.2.0 of `phonrule`.  But there is nothing else in the documentation regarding alignment.

I need it to be the standard left-aligned version - that is, left-aligned output *and* left-aligned environment.  Something like this (exact spacing is flexible):

[image]

Trying to throw in any type of alignment generally breaks the `phonrule` environment and it won't compile *or* it aligns the entire figure/example, rather than just the individual (output + environment) sections.

I have been using roughly the same as the other answer from the above question which utilizes `\mbox`.  This is fine, but adding  additional outputs and environments is either messy or requires a new command based on the differences.  `phonrule` generally does all this in a much cleaner and more expandable way, which is why I'm looking into being able to modify the alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete reimplementation of `phonrule`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand*{\textrightarrow}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
\providecommand*{\textplus}{\ensuremath{+}}
\providecommand*{\textminus}{\ensuremath{-}}

\newcommand*{\phold}{\rule[-1.5pt]{1.5ex}{.5pt}}

\newcommand*{\phon}[2]{#1 \textrightarrow{} #2}
\newcommand*{\phonc}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3}
\newcommand*{\phonr}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~\phold#3}
\newcommand*{\phonl}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3\phold}
\newcommand*{\phonb}[4]{\phonl{#1}{#2}{#3}#4}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\env}{\@ifstar{\@env{&}}{\@env{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@env}[3]{#2~/#1#3}

\newcommand*{\envr}{\@ifstar{\@envr{&}}{\@envr{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@envr}[3]{\@env{#1}{#2}{\phold#3}}
\newcommand*{\envl}{\@ifstar{\@envl{&}}{\@envl{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@envl}[3]{\@env{#1}{#2}{#3\phold}}
\newcommand*{\envb}{\@ifstar{\@envb{&}}{\@envb{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@envb}[4]{\@env{#1}{#2}{#3\phold#4}}

% set environment for feature matrix with square brackets
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\oneof}[2][c]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{#1#1}#2\end{tabular}
    \right.
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\phon{x}{\oneof[l]{ \envr*{w}{z} \\
      \envl*{v}{\phonfeat{
      \textplus feature x \\
      \textminus feature y
}}}}

\phon{x}{\oneof[l]{
   \envr{w}{z} \\
   \envl{v}{\phonfeat{
   \textplus feature x \\
   \textminus feature y
}}}}

\phon{x}{\oneof{
   \envr{w}{z} \\
   \envl{v}{\phonfeat{
   \textplus feature x \\
   \textminus feature y
}}}}

\end{document}
```

The changes are:

1. The `\oneof` command accepts an optional argument for the inner alignment, default `c` like in the original; it can be `l` or `r`.
2. The commands `\env`, `\envl`, `\envr` and `\envb` have a *-form, which inserts an `&` after `/` instead of the default `~`, so they can be used in the argument of `\oneof` in order to get the alignment you wish.

In the code above I used all three possibilities; the first example is what you're looking for, the second one just has left alignment, the final one is like the original.

[image]

Comment: Definitely overkill, but the options you created will help with flexibility or potentially changing preferences later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define a new command `\oneofl` by adding the line

```
\newcommand\oneofl[1]{\ensuremath{\left\{\begin{tabular}{l} #1 \end{tabular}\right.}}
```

to your preamble (i.e., between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`) and use it instead of `\oneof`. Then you get the following output by the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\newcommand\oneofl[1]{\ensuremath{\left\{\begin{tabular}{l} #1 \end{tabular}\right.}}
\begin{document}

\phon{x}{\oneofl{
\envr{w}{z} \\
\envl{v}{\phonfeat{
+feature x \\
-feature y}}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is actually quite nice, but I chose egreg's answer because it is more comprehensive and gives several additional options that I don't need but could be useful in the future.  Wish I could accept both as answers for different reasons.

Comment: By the way, the image you includes seems like the underscore before z and the left bracket are not perfectly aligned with each other...  I was a bit curious why and if there's a way to tweak them to line up?

Comment: @whatisit Thanks for the note. The aligned material was typeset in math mode instead of text mode; spacing is different in this case. I have corrected it.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the explanation.  I don't really use math mode so I wouldn't have thought of that.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to include both, in case someone sees this in the future and prefers either or.