# Typesetting linguistic rewrite rule

Tags: horizontal-alignment, brackets, linguistics

I'm trying to (more or less) replicate this phonological rewrite rule:

[image]

I'm using the package [`phonrule`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/phonrule), and what I manage to accomplish is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\begin{document}

\phonc
    {\phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ +hi}}
    {[$\alpha$grv]}
    {\oneof{%
        \phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$grv}\phold\\
        \phold\phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$vce}%
    }}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My main problem here is what appears after the "when" slash:

(1) The package only provides a left curly bracket - how can I add a right one as well?

(2) The two options within the curly brackets are not well aligned. I think comparing the two pictures themselves says it better than what I could do with words.

Comment: in redard to (2): According phonrule.sty \oneof internally uses a simple tabular environment. If you insert an ampersand (eg. like this: `\phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$grv} & \phold`) and add a second newline `\\ \\` the result looks not perfect but a little bit better ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the reimplementation of `phonrule` I did for [Alignment in \oneof from the phonrule package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342163/alignment-in-oneof-from-the-phonrule-package)

We can now define a variant of `\oneof` where the closing brace is added and the space between columns is removed.

```
\documentclass{article}

% BEGIN reimplementation of phonrule
\providecommand*{\textrightarrow}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
\providecommand*{\textplus}{\ensuremath{+}}
\providecommand*{\textminus}{\ensuremath{-}}

\newcommand*{\phold}{\rule[-1.5pt]{1.5ex}{.5pt}}

\newcommand*{\phon}[2]{#1 \textrightarrow{} #2}
\newcommand*{\phonc}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3}
\newcommand*{\phonr}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~\phold#3}
\newcommand*{\phonl}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3\phold}
\newcommand*{\phonb}[4]{\phonl{#1}{#2}{#3}#4}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\env}{\@ifstar{\@env{&}}{\@env{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@env}[3]{#2~/#1#3}

\newcommand*{\envr}{\@ifstar{\@envr{&}}{\@envr{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@envr}[3]{\@env{#1}{#2}{\phold#3}}
\newcommand*{\envl}{\@ifstar{\@envl{&}}{\@envl{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@envl}[3]{\@env{#1}{#2}{#3\phold}}
\newcommand*{\envb}{\@ifstar{\@envb{&}}{\@envb{~}}}
\newcommand*{\@envb}[4]{\@env{#1}{#2}{#3\phold#4}}

% set environment for feature matrix with square brackets
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\oneof}[2][c]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{#1#1}#2\end{tabular}
    \right.
  }%
}
\makeatother
% END

\newcommand{\oneofvar}[2][c]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{#1@{}#1}#2\end{tabular}
    \right\}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\phonc
    {\phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ +hi}}
    {[$\alpha$grv]}
    {\oneofvar{%
        \phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$grv} & \hrulefill \\
        \hrulefill & \phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$vce}%
    }}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add the `@{}c@{}` bit (from Alan's answer) to the `tabular` definition of `\oneof` and `\oneofvar` to get the braces closer?

Comment: @Sverre If you remove the `@{}` from the `\oneofvar` definition it is the same as mine. (And personally I wouldn't use `\hrulefill` here, since the environment line is way too long and high.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, but I was wondering how I can put the `@{}c@{}` bit into the definition of `\oneofvar`/`\twoof` (I renamed it `\phonbraces`), so that I don't need to repeat it every time I write a rule.

Comment: @Sverre Just replace the `[c]` in the macro definition with `@{}c@{}`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that looks ok. I added a `\twoof` command for the second brace and made a longer `\phold` command `\Phold`. Since the underlying commands are tabular you can pass any tabular specification to it so I removed the intercolumn space to make the alignment look a bit nicer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\twoof}[2][c]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{#1#1}#2\end{tabular}
    \right\}
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\Phold}{\rule[-4pt]{2.5em}{.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\phonc
    {\phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ +hi}}
    {[$\alpha$grv]}
    {\twoof[@{}c@{}]{%
        \phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$grv} & \Phold\\
        \Phold & \phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$vce}%
    }}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I was hoping you would come to the rescue, Alan `:)` Now as a follow-up: could you _please_ make a package for phonological rewrite rules?

Comment: I'll add this to the list of "packages I've been asked to write in TeX.se comments". :)

Comment: @Sverre And see, egreg has already rewritten the package!

Answer (score 1):

Using [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365129/9077) as the basis, and incorporating something from [Alan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365124/9077) as well as adding a few bits of my own, I've decided on this (stripping away lines I don't need for this MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand*{\textrightarrow}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\phoncrossbar}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\newcommand*{\phon}[2]{#1 \textrightarrow{} #2}
\newcommand*{\phonc}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\phonbraces}[2][@{}c@{}]{% for curly braces on both sides
    \ensuremath{%
    \left\{
        \begin{tabular}{#1#1}#2\end{tabular}
    \right\}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\phonc
    {\phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ +hi}}
    {[$\alpha$grv]}
    {\phonbraces{%
        \phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$grv} & \phoncrossbar\\
        \\
        \phoncrossbar & \phonfeat{$-$cnt\\ $\alpha$vce}%
    }}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I've changed from egreg's answer is this:

(1) Created a version of `\hrulefill` called `\phoncrossbar` that has the same thickness (0.5pt) as rules used elsewhere here.

(2) Added `@{}c@{}` to the definition of `\phonfeat` and `\phonbraces` to remove extra white space in matrices and around braces (this is also how it normally looks in the literature).

(3) Left aligned the features in the feature matrix (which is the norm).

Comment: This is an aesthetic choice, of course, but to my eye the bar is still too long and too high.

Comment: @AlanMunn I had the same doubts, but I compared with _SPE_, and that's how they do it, actually.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be the only thing about SPE that's ugly. :)