# Writing a rewrite rule (phonrule)

Tags: tables, brackets, linguistics

I'm trying to recreate this rewrite rule:

[image]

Using a modified version of [`phonrule`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/phonrule) (see [Typesetting linguistic rewrite rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365105/typesetting-linguistic-rewrite-rule)), I get this:

[image]

There are several issues here, and I'm wary about asking several questions at once, but since each question can be solved independently of the others, I'll ask them all now.

1. How can I get a larger slash that's more or less proportional to the size of whatever directly follows it?
2. How can I get large parenthetical brackets proportional to the largest item between them?
3. How can I replicate the content of the final matrix, such the `V` is centered, but `-round` and `-low` are left aligned?
4. How can I get a subscript 0 to be at the bottom of a matrix?

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand*{\textrightarrow}{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
\providecommand*{\textminus}{\ensuremath{-}}
\newcommand*{\phold}{\rule[-1.5pt]{1em}{.5pt}}
\newcommand*{\phon}[2]{#1 \textrightarrow{} #2}
\newcommand*{\phonl}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}~/~#3\phold}

% set environment for feature matrix with square brackets
\newcommand*{\phonfeatc}[1]{% features are centered
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }}

\begin{document}
\phonl{\phonfeatc{V\\ +back}}{[$\alpha$back]}{{\phonfeatc{V\\ $\alpha$back}} (C$_{0}$\phonfeatc{V\\ \textminus\,round\\ \textminus\,low}$_{0}$ C$_{0}$)$_{0}$ \# X}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**REVISED ANSWER**

This is not my field, but after OP comments, I learned that these bracketed expressions have a centered top row if it a single `V` or `C` (or left-aligned otherwise) and subsequent row(s), of arbitrary number, are all left-aligned.  If that is so, then this approach I think is more consistent than my original answer.

In it, there are not separate `\phonefeatc{}` and `\phonfeatcl{}{}`, but rather just `\phonfeat{}{}`, in which the 1st argument is the top, centered if `V` or `C`, left-aligned otherwise, and the 2nd argument are all the rest of the left-aligned qualifiers.  To handle an arbitrary number of rows, I place the nested stack in a `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,amsmath}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\newcommand*{\phold}{\rule[-1.5pt]{1em}{.5pt}}
\newcommand*{\phon}[2]{#1 \rightarrow{} #2}
\newcommand*{\phonl}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}\stretchrel{~/~}{#3}\phold}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[2]{%
  \left[
  \def\stacktype{L}
  \ifx V#1\def\stackalignment{c}\else
    \ifx C#1\def\stackalignment{c}\else
      \def\stackalignment{l}
    \fi
  \fi
  \vcenter{\hbox{\stackon{\Longunderstack[l]{#2}}{#1}}}\right]}
\begin{document}
$\phonl{\phonfeat{V}{+back}}{[\alpha\text{back}]}{\phonfeat{V}{$\alpha$back} 
  \left(\text{C}_0\phonfeat{V}{$-$\,round\\ $-$\,low}_0 \text{C}_0\right)_{\!\!0} \# X
}$\bigskip

$\phonl{\phonfeat{V}{+back}}{[\alpha\text{back}]}{\phonfeat{V}{$\alpha$back} 
  \left(\text{C}_0\phonfeat{V}{$-$\,round\\ $-$\,low\\$-$\,xxx}_0 \text{C}_0\right)_{\!\!0} \# X
}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I did some adaptation to stacks.  It also now runs in math mode, though arguments to `\phonfeatc` and `\phonefeatcl` are still processed in text mode.

1. To get the enlarged slash, I used the `\stretchrel`, which vertically stretches its 1st argument (here `~/~`) to match the vertical footprint of its second argument (here, `#3` of `\phonl`).
2. By converting the macros to be processed in math mode, I could employ `\left(...\right)` directly, to grow the parens to the proper size.
3. To get the proper alignment of the 3-level vector, I employed a nested stack in the form of the macro `\phonfeatcl`, in which the bottom 2 rows are a left-aligned `\Longunderstack` and the top row gets stacked, centered, atop it.
4. Because processing proceeds in math mode, the subscripts will properly attach to the vertical base of what precedes them.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,amsmath}
\strutlongstacks{T}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\newcommand*{\phold}{\rule[-1.5pt]{1em}{.5pt}}
\newcommand*{\phon}[2]{#1 \rightarrow{} #2}
\newcommand*{\phonl}[3]{\phon{#1}{#2}\stretchrel{~/~}{#3}\phold}
\newcommand*{\phonfeatc}[1]{% features are centered
  \left[\Centerstack{#1}\right]}
\newcommand*{\phonfeatcl}[2]{% features are centered
  \left[\def\stacktype{L}\stackon{\Longunderstack[l]{#2}}{#1}\right]}
\begin{document}
$\phonl{\phonfeatc{V\\ +back}}{[\alpha\text{back}]}{\phonfeatc{V\\ $\alpha$back} 
  \left(\text{C}_0\phonfeatcl{V}{$-$\,round\\ $-$\,low}_0 \text{C}_0\right)_{\!\!0} \# X
}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you comment on how you achieved the various things I asked for in my question? I really have no idea what all these "stack" commands are doing.

Comment: @Sverre Done, per your request.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do the brackets in the last matrix not fully enclose its content vertically?

Comment: @Sverre I have just added `\strutlongstacks{T}` to the preamble to remedy that.

Comment: For `\phonfeatcl`, if I need a matrix with three left aligned rows below the top `V`, do I change `\Longunderstack[l]{#2}` to `\Longunderstack[l]{#3}`?

Comment: @Sverre Please see if my revised answer provides what you need.  Part of my problem is I don't understand the required syntax of this "language" that you present.

Comment: I was just curious what I would do in a case where I had three instead of two rows below the "V", since I don't understand the code of your command `\phonfeatcl` very well. In general, the elements within matrices are left aligned, but in the cases where people put a single symbol as the top element ('V' for 'vowel' or 'C' for 'consonant'), that one symbol is usually centered, because it looks ugly when it's left aligned. It's not generally the case that the top element is centered and the rest left aligned.

Comment: @Sverre I have re-edited, to make the top row centered only if it is a lone `V` or `C`, left-aligned otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64251/discussion-between-sverre-and-steven-b-segletes).