# How to prevent package from interfering with \hfill

Tags: fill

Consider this MWE (stuff taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365158/9077)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\phoncrossbar}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}
\makeatother

%\usepackage[notipa]{ot-tableau}

\begin{document}
\phonfeat{\phoncrossbar\\ +abcdefg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I uncomment the line loading [`ot-tableau`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ot-tableau), the `\hrule` no longer fills the space within the brackets:

[image]

How can I prevent the `ot-tableau` package from doing this (hopefully without wrecking some necessary function of that package)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is `colortbl`. The problem can be cured with higher order infinite glue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\phoncrossbar}{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height .5pt\hskip 0pt plus 1filll\kern\z@ 
}
\newcommand*{\phonfeat}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \left[\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right]%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}abcdef\\\hrulefill\end{tabular}

\phonfeat{\phoncrossbar\\ +abcdefg}

\end{document}
```

As you see, `\hrulefill` doesn't really fill the line, but the modified `\phoncrossbar` does.

[image]

Comment: Seems to do the trick!